# regex to coordinates WGS84?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying this regular expressión, but I can't validate correctly the end white space and the letter:

```
/^\d{0,2}(\-\d{0,2})?(\-\d{0,2})?(\ ?\d[W,E]?)?$/
```

Examples of correct values:

1. 33-39-10 N   //OK
2. 85-50 W      //OK
3. -85-50 E      //Wrong

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`\d{0,2}` this [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) also matches a digit zero times so that would match the leading `-` in the 3rd example.

In the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[W,E]` you could omit the comma and list the characters you allow to match `[ENW]`

If only the third group is optional you could try including the whitespace before the end of the line `$`

[`^\d{2}(-\d{2})(-\d{2})? [ENW] $`](https://regex101.com/r/9C7qqw/1)

Comment: I vouch for @Thefourthbird answer as it is more robust. Plus his regex works multiline.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this regular expression : `^(?!\-)\d{0,2}?(\-\d{0,2}).+\s(N|E|W|S)$`

Using a `negative lookahead`, we have excluded anything that starts with a dash (`-`).

- `(?!\-)` = `Starting at the current position in the expression,
  ensures that the given pattern will not match`
- `\s(N|E|W|S)` matches anything with a space (`\s`) and one of the letters using OR operator `|`.
- You may also use `\s+(N|E|W|S)`.
- `+` = `Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as
  possible, giving back as needed`